# Dreaming about Eliyahu HaNavi

Tags: eliyahu-hanavi, dream

I've heard from some people that one can't "choose" to dream about Elyahu HaNavi and that whenever one dreams about him it's **for sure** the **true** Eliyahu HaNavi, meaning, it was the prophet himself showing up in the dream, with a message or something.

Now, *if the above is true*, then whatever Eliyahu says in the dream must necessarily be true, otherwise he would be spreading lies around, no?

So, is the above true? Is there a source for that?

Comment: Why not ask those people you heard it from for a source?

Comment: Well, I only remember one person, my father in law, and I will ask but I'm mostly an "indoors" person, go out once a week or so...

Comment: Have you ever heard of that?

Comment: heard of what? Indoor people? Yes. Dreams about Eliyahu ? Don't think so. The Gemara in Brachos (from 55a onwards) talks about dreams, but Eliyahu is not mentioned. (He's mentioned 15 times in Brachos in other contexts.)

Comment: +1 for the funny part. I've been looking around and can't find anything... :-/

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can find is the song אֵלִיָּהוּ הַנָּבִיא sung by many on Motzai Shabbat.

It can be [found in most Siddurim](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01547.html#HtmpReportNum0022_L3).

The second to last verse is `אַשְׁרֵי מִי שֶׁרָאָה פָנָיו בַּחֲלוֹם, אַשְׁרֵי מִי שֶׁנָּתַן לוֹ שָׁלוֹם, וְהֶחֱזִיר לוֹ שָׁלוֹם` - *happy is the one who sees him (Eliyahu Hanavi) in a dream, happy is one who was given Shalom (greeted) by Eliyahu Hanavi.*

This makes it sound that merely seeing Eliyahu Hanavi in a dream is a big deal; and not something that simply happens as a result of thinking about him during the day (which is the cause of most dreams).

However, it doesn't talk about the veracity of any message Eliyahu Hanavi may tell you in a dream. (Nor does it mention how to identify him.)

Comment: Cool, I mean, In my dreams he was almost always "clearly" Eliyahu HaNavi, once people at a Beit Knesset identified him as such and urged to tell me who he was etc while in another instance all members of a beit din (maybe sanhedrin? there were way too many people) were also shocked by his appearance in the court (they were all known big Poskim, Rabanim and Mekubalim of today) after I called for his help etc. In the other hand, once he showed me the Olam Haba etc but didn't identify himself as Eliyahu HaNavi, I just figured it out weeks later...

Answer (score 1):

It is a common practice in Gedolim to not immediately listen to a dream unless it repeats itself three times.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer... Does it need to be the same "exact" dream or is enough if what Elyahu HaNavi tells me is the same thing?

Comment: You should expand on this and add sources as well as specifics

Comment: +Jake Armstrong I believe it doesn't have to be the exact dream but a dream in which the same things happen. But I don't really have a source for that...